# Serviço parou de funcionar ao gerar o gráfico

Tags: c#, xamarin

Estava tendo problemas com a geração de uma gráfico, que está resolvido. O código abaixo estava ok e de repente parou, ou seja, o serviço não está sendo executado por conta não sei de que. No momento em que eu chamo o **GetService** não não vem nada, a ***var itensgrid*** permanece nula.

```
public class DataModelGrid
    {
        DataService dataService = new DataService();
        public List<LiberacaoItensGrid> itensGrid = new List<LiberacaoItensGrid>();
        public List<GeraGrafico> GeraChart { get; set; }
        public double IdOrcamento { get; set; }
        public double TotalVenda { get; set; }
        public double TotalLucro { get; set; }
        public DataModelGrid(double id)
        {
            GetService(id);
            GeraChart = new List<GeraGrafico>();
            GeraChart.Add(new GeraGrafico() { Assunto = "Vendas", Total = TotalVenda });
            GeraChart.Add(new GeraGrafico() { Assunto = "Lucro", Total = TotalLucro });
        }        
        public async void GetService(double id)
        {
            itensGrid = await dataService.GetDataGrid(id);
            foreach(var item in itensGrid)
            {
                this.IdOrcamento = item.IdOrcamento;
                this.TotalVenda = item.TotalVenda;
                this.TotalLucro = item.TotalLucro;
            }
        }
        public class GeraGrafico
        {
            public string Assunto { get; set; }
            public double Total { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Esse é o código que uso para pegar meu serviço

```
public async Task<List<LiberacaoItensGrid>> GetDataGrid(double id)
        {
            try
            {
                string url = $"http://www.inetglobal.com.br/autorizador/api/getliberaitens/{id}";
                var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
                var itenslib = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LiberacaoItensGrid>>(response);
                return itenslib.ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

O problema que estava funcionando e não sei o que eu fiz. Já dei Ctrl+Z até voltar ao nada, fui fazendo Ctrl+Shift+Z e testando cada etapa passada e não consegui êxito.

Por que não estou mais conseguindo pegar informações que vem do meu serviço com esses códigos? O que tá errado? Quando acerto uma coisa, falho em outra. Uma no cravo e outra na ferradura.

**EDIT1**

Tá dando esse erro

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered
>   while parsing value: S. Path '', line 0, position 0.   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue () [0x002b3] in
>   :0    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read () [0x0004c] in
>   :0    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadAndMoveToContent () [0x00000] in
>   :0    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType
>   (Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, System.Boolean
>   hasConverter) [0x00043] in :0    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize
>   (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType,
>   System.Boolean checkAdditionalContent) [0x000db] in
>   :0    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal
>   (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) [0x00053]
>   in :0    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader
>   reader, System.Type objectType) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject (System.String value,
>   System.Type type, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings)
>   [0x0002d] in :0    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T] (System.String value,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T] (System.String value)
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Autorizador.Service.DataService+d__4.MoveNext ()
>   [0x0005b] in
>   C:\Labs\Autorizador\Autorizador\Autorizador\Service\DataService.cs:60
>   }

Para esse código

```
public async Task<List<LiberacaoItensGrid>> GetDataGrid(double id)
        {
            try
            {
                //string url = $"http://www.inetglobal.com.br/autorizador/api/getliberaitens/{id}";
                //var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
                //var itenslib = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LiberacaoItensGrid>>(response);
                var client = new HttpClient();
                string url = $"http://www.inetglobal.com.br/autorizador/api/getliberaitens/{id}";
                var response = client.GetStringAsync(url);

                response.Wait(); // use assim ou com o while ....
                var itenslib = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LiberacaoItensGrid>>(response.ToString());

                while (response.Status != System.Threading.Tasks.TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
                {

                }

                return itenslib.ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Se você chamar diretamente a url da api com o seu ID o resultado aparece?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, então, eu coloqiei um break na chamada do serviço e tá assim. Ele monta a URL corretamente, passando o parâmetro correto. Porém, quando chega aqui `var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);` aí ele sai do método. Só quero entender porque se já funcionou e agora não. Não entra no catch, apenas sai do método.

Comment: Acredito que isso qui esteja dando "pau": `await client.GetStringAsync(url);` tentei chamar diretamente e continua saindo do método.

Comment: tente usar o client.GetStringAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza, já havia feito isso e mesmo assim continua com problemas. Não entendo, chegou a funcionar, por três vezes eu entrei no break e agora nada.

Comment: Sua API esta funcionado ?

Comment: Sim, carrego pelo Postman e o resultado vem. Está OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

altere seu Wait da seguinte forma.

```
var client = new HttpClient();
string url = $"http://www.inetglobal.com.br/autorizador/api/getliberaitens/{id}";
var response = client.GetStringAsync(url);

response.Wait(); // use assim ou com o while ....

while(response.Status != System.Threading.Tasks.TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
{

}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Solução no [Git](https://github.com/MarconcilioSouza/Projetos/tree/master/TesteAPI_Request)

Comment: Marconcilio, vc marcou o método como void. Como eu faria para carregar minha model a partir dele?

Comment: só marquei como void porque não tenho seu modelo você tem que simplesmente usar o jsonconvert para sua classe .. como estava fazendo  var itenslib = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LiberacaoItensGrid>>(response);

Comment: Ou isso não esta funcionado também ?

Comment: É que levei ao pé da letra seu exemplo, mas vou alterar para retornar uma Task<T> e ver o que acontece. Só uma dúvida: dentro do seu while não há nada, devo manter assim?

Comment: Melhor o response.Wait(); mas se você quiser fazer alguma outra coisa enquanto aguarda o retorno pode usar o while. fica a seu critério.

Comment: Fiz uma edição para mostrar o erro

Comment: Acho que no meu código anterior, faltava isso: `var client = new HttpClient();`. Dessa forma, funcionou com o meu código original.

Comment: Voltou a dar o problema, parou de funcionar. Não me sinto segura levar isso amanhã para meu cliente. Voltou a dar o mesmo problema que estava dando, ou seja, no response ele aborta. Isso pode ter a ver em modo debug? Será?

Comment: ai já não sei o que pode ser.

Comment: Marconcilio, o seu código dá um erro. Nessa linha `var itenslib = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LiberacaoItensGrid>>(response);` ele pede para response ser convertido para uma string e quando eu faço isso, dá erro de caracter não reconhecido

Comment: var itenslib = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LiberacaoItensGrid>>(response.Result.ToString());

Comment: O erro é: Não é possível converter `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> para string`. Como se resolve esse erro?